# How to do replacements within a list based on an equivalence table using Excel Powerquery?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am importing data into Excel from an external JSON and I'm using Powerquery to format/filter/adapt the table as needed.

There is one thing I cannot manage to do: doing lookup/replacement of list items based on a "correspondance" table I have in the same Excel workbook, in different worksheet.

JSON is like (newlines added by me, just sample content):

```
{"Name": "COVID-19.pdf",
 "Title": "Antibodies in the fight against COVID-19",
 "Categories": ["Biotechnology", "Covid19"]
}
```

The lookup/replacement table I have is structured, for example, like this:

| original | replacement |
| --- | --- |
| covid19 | COVID-19 |
| covid | COVID-19 |
| covid-19 | COVID-19 |
| ... | ... |

and so on, so it's a many-to-one replacement rule.

How can I tell Powerquery to check each element of the list "Categories" and, if found, replace it with the one indicated in the table?

Edit: this is my current set of actions for the JSON:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://...")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Name", "Title", "Categories"}, {"Name", "Title", "Categories"}),
    
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

Comment: See my last edit of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide much information, so you'll have to adapt this to your existing code.

Assume you have a column named `Categories` in your main query, you can do something like this:

```
//Read your correspondence table into your query
    tbl = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="correspondenceTable"]}[Content],
    corrTable = Table.TransformColumnTypes(tbl, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(tbl), each {_, type text})),

//Then you can transform your categories column
    #"Replace" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step",{"Categories", 
        each try corrTable[replacement]{List.PositionOf(corrTable[original], _)} otherwise _})
```

***Categories Column***
[image]

***Correspondence Table***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

***Edit:***
From your comment below, it seems that, for some reason, you want to apply the replacements **before** expanding the lists of Categories into separate cells.

In that case, assuming the `Categories` columns contains a `List` of categories, then you could use this formula instead:

```
    Replace = Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step", {"Categories", (L)=>List.Transform(L, 
        each 
            try 
                corrTable[replacement]
                    {List.PositionOf(corrTable[original], _, Occurrence.First, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)}
            otherwise _
        )})
```

Comment: It doesn't fail and I can see each step of loading is working, but it doesn't replace anything. Is it maybe because each cell of the column "Categories" is not a simple string but a list of items?

Comment: I tried to replace your last line to add a list transform but I think I didn't do it right: #"Replace" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step",{"Categories", 
        each try List.Transform(_, corrTable[replacement]{List.PositionOf(corrTable[original])} ) otherwise _})

Comment: @FarO  As I wrote in my answer, you don't provide much information. Your example, when you expand the Categories record list in Power query, resolves into a single item per cell.  If you want to change the items in the list BEFORE expanding them, you'd need a different formula.  Is that what you want?

Comment: It works, thanks! Since I would like to post a good question, do you think I should add more details, for future readers? or is the current set of actions enough? I didn't put any detail about the correspondence table since it's totally arbitrary, as you posted.

Comment: @FarO I don't think you need to.  But maybe just change the title to "*How to do replacements within a list based on an equivalence table using Excel Powerquery?*